# How to map Alt-n to Down with sxhkd?

Tags: linux

I am trying to map Alt + n to down with sxhkd, but it doesn't work and I am not sure why. I have the following config, and I can confirm that it is loading correctly:

This is my `config`

```
  alt + n
    xte "key Down"
  alt + p
    xte "key Up"
```

I run this with `sxhkd -c ./configFile`, but it has not effect. Am I configuring it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using [xvkbd](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xvkbd_tutorial.html)

```
# up
alt + p
    xvkbd -text '\A\[Prior]'

# down
alt + n
    xvkbd -text '\A\[Next]'
```

Answer (score 0):

`Alt` and `n` is still pressed, when the command is run, but until one of the keys is released, sxhkd seems to keep waiting for further input, which swallows the event. It works though, if you use sxhkds "on release" mapping: `alt + @n` (or even `@alt + n` or `@alt + @n`)